# How do I deploy the data to the %programdata% directory when compiling a executebal in vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, connection-string

I created.exe file and installed it on my machine.When I insert data I get an error "Failed to update database "Database.mdf" because database file is read-only". I am able to view the data but cannot insert the data. I am using local sql database and visual studio 2019. My connection string is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HovedDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

I have read a lot of topics on the forum about this and so fare I have changed the settings to the db in the SSMS, so that it is not longer a permisson issue.

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

But it still gives the same error. One thing I havent tried, because of lack of skill, is deploying the data to the  %programdata% directory. It looks like this advice is given regarding this issue. So anybody have a idea on how to do this in Visual Studio. I am pretty new to this so dont be afraid to give detailed instructions :) Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You would normally use an installer to place files in specific locations so it's not really a job for your app itself. If you are just copying the program files onto another machine then you can just copy the data file wherever you want it, but that's not a job that a normal user should have to perform, hence the use of installers.

Comment: Note that, if you do place your data file outside the program folder, you will have to either set the connection string at run time or else change the path that `"|DataDirectory|" maps to, which you'd also do at run time.